# Computational Complexity Order

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have around 8 algorithms with varying Time Complexity and I would like to know the order of them from the slowest to the fastest.

```
(Algorith1) O(n^3)
(Algorith2) O(1)
(Algorith3) O(log(n) + n)
(Algorith4) O(nlog(n))
(Algorith5) O(log(n))
(Algorith6) O(n^2 + nlog(n))
(Algorith7) O(n!)
(Algorith8) O(2^n)
```

I know that the slowest and worst performance is O(n!) but what comes next out of the rest.

Comment: The simplest way is to graph them and compare their slopes as `n` increases.

Comment: factorial is slower than exponential which is slower than polynomial which is slower than logarithmic which is slower than constant. the sub-orders are very easy to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not graph them and check for Big-O!  Asymptotic complexity is not that simple, you need to account for all possible constants out in front and being added (for example O(100n + log(n) is still equivalent to O(n)).  This all being said, for sufficiently large n and an arbitrary constant in front:

```
O(1) << O(log(n)) << O(log(n) + n) << O(nlog(n)) << O(n^2 + nlog(n)) << O(n^3) << O(2^n) << O(n!)
```